# How to increase two values to match a ratio of 17:8 in Google Sheets

Tags: math, google-sheets, fractions

**If I have two values with a calculated ratio for example:**

```
Value 1 = 5000
Value 2 = 100

Calculated Ratio = 50:1
```

How do I distribute a value of **500** between value 1 and value 2 so I can get to a 17:8 ratio or as close as possible to 17:8 ratio without decreasing any of the values.

I tried adding all the values and then splitting them into 17:8 ratio but this will in some cases decrease one value to get to another.

**Incorrect example as value one has decreased from its original value of 5000:**

```
Value 1 = 3808
Value 2 = 1792
Calculated Ratio = 17:8
```

Comment: It seems the best you can do is 100 + 500 => 600, still leaving you with a ratio of about 8:1

Answer (score 1):

You have two equations and two unknowns. The two unknowns are the adjustment values `a` and `b` such as the ratio below is known (17/8)

```
aspect = (value1+a)/(value2+b)
```

but the combined value of the adjustments has to be a fixed amount (500)

```
sum = a + b
```

### Soution 1

The solution if the aspect ratio is `float` type value `17/8=2.125`, then the solution is

```
a = (aspect*(value2+sum) - value1)/(aspect+1)
b = (value1 - aspect*value2+sum)/(aspect+1)
```

In your case I get `a = -1192` and `b = 1692` for

```
value1 + a = 3808
value2 + b = 1792
```

The ratio `3808/1792 = 17/8` and the sum `(1692) + (-1192) = 500`

### Solution 2

The solution if the aspect ratio is a rational number `aspect = num/den` is:

```
a = (num*(value2+sum) - den*value1)/(den + num)
b = (den*(value1+sum) - num*value2)/(den + num)
```

and again the sample calculation is (`num=17`, `den=8`)

```
a = (17*(100+500) - 8*5000)/(8 + 17) = -1192
b = (8*(5000+500) - 17*100)/(8 + 17) = +1692
```

### Adjustments

If you constrain `a>=0` and `a<=sum` as well as `b>=0` and `b<=sum` then you would not reach the aspect ratio.

You can do this will the following code adjusting `a` and `b`

```
if (a<0)
{
    a = 0;
    b = sum;
} 
else if(b<0)
{
    a = sum;
    b = 0; 
}
```

### Graph

Graphically this problem is a follows:

The blue line is the combination of Value 1 and Value 2 that have the aspect ratio desired.

The pink dot is the starting value `(5000,100)`.

The slanted lines are the adjusted Value 1 and Value 2 for a given `sum` amount to adjust by. I have included lines for 500, 1000, 2000, and 4000.

Where the slanted lines intersect the blue line is the ideal solution. The solution

[image: fig]

The red dot is where the above solution(s) lead you before adjustments. After adjusting for non-negative `a` and `b` you will end up at the black dot.

In google sheets, you need some extra columns to implement the above

[image: fig2]

Comment: Hi John, this is a great answer and the same one I got to, however the problem is that neither value is allowed to decrease at all. So you have to add 500 and then get as close as possible to 17:8 ratio between the two values.

Comment: @Ewald that wasn't a requirement in the question. At least not specified explicitly. If you force `a` and `b` to be positive only then you might not have a solution. So how do you deal with this situation? Are you ok with not reaching the aspect ratio, or to increase the sum?

Comment: It's ok to not reach the ratio if it's not possible. If I can reach the ratio as close as possible then that is success.

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to sheets and is a basic math cross multiplication problem

So, 17 is to 8 as 500 is to x

17/8 = 500/x

Cross multiplying give us

8 * 500 = 4,000

17 * x  = 17x

solving for x

x = 4,000/17

x = 235.29

Answer (score 0):

This was a really fun problem thanks for sharing it. [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z9WP7Zk7JsV-zoVrZcrfqw5KNS_L0FWFBREiL8X5ozE/edit?usp=sharing)

Spoiler alert! The integers are 5302 and 298 with a final ratio of 17.79 which can be found in row 303.

Edit 1:
I misunderstood the question. A 17:8 ratio can be simplified to 2.125:1. The spreadsheet lists all of the possible combinations, where the smallest ratio is 8.35:1. Thus it doesn't seem there is a solution close to a 17:8 ratio.